# Check if SKAction is running

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

How do I check if a `SKAction` has finished its animation?

I need to check if my action has already finished or is still performing its action. After that I want to create a boolean to avoid multiple actions during the main action.

```
SKAction *lionJumpActionComplete = [lionNode actionForKey:@"lionIsJumping"];
    lionJumpActionComplete = [SKAction sequence: @[lionJumpActionUp, lionJumpActionFly, lionJumpActionDown, lionJumpActionPause]];

    if (lionJumpActionComplete) {
        return;
    }

    [lionNode runAction:lionJumpActionComplete withKey:@"lionIsJumping"];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is the only action running on your node, you can check this using:

```
if (!lionNode.hasActions) { // check if no actions are running on this node
   // action code here
}
```

Alternatively, you can set your boolean in a completion block that gets called after the action runs and completes:

```
[lionNode runAction:[SKAction sequence: @[lionJumpActionUp, lionJumpActionFly, lionJumpActionDown, lionJumpActionPause]] completion:^{
    BOOL isActionCompleted = YES;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of me creating a walking animation on a node. Before I create it again I make sure the previous one has finished by looking for its key.

```
    SKAction *animAction = [self actionForKey:@"WalkingZombie"];

    if (animAction) {
        return; // we already have a running animation
    }

    [self runAction:
        [SKAction animateWithTextures:[self walkAnimationFrames]
                         timePerFrame:1.0f/15.0f
                               resize:YES
                              restore:NO]
            withKey:@"WalkingZombie"];
}
```

Comment: Can we get more context as to what didn't work? Did you register your action with a key?

Comment: The action now only fires one time instead of every time I touch the screen (except when the action is running)

Comment: You can have a completion block get invoked after an action completes. Is that more along the lines of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the node is running the action

so in this case

```
if (![self hasActions]) {
     [self runAction:[self actionForKey:@"ZombieAction"]];
}
```

probably better might be

```
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatForever:[self actionForKey:@"zombieAction"]]];
```

which will keep doing the action forever.